socket io disconnects when my unity game goes to background for more than 20 seconds
i am using socket.io 2.3.0 version with unity c# to handle realtime communication for my multiplayer game. and i am facing issue where the socket disconnects when the app is goes to the background for around 20 sec. when i return to the game the connection is lost from the server, how prevent the unity thread should be in always background without killing. help me to resolve this.
My current setup is:

Client using BestHTTP socket.io plugin.
Server using node js with socket.io v2.3.0

Flow:

The socket works fine while the app is the forground.
when the app goes to background for apprx 20 secs the socket disconnects.
it does not reconnect automatically when the app is came back to the foreground.


I would probably rather go for reconnect the socket when it is coming back to foreground... you can track this using OnApplicationFocus and OnApplicationPause
